# Maximise, minimise and close buttons for each section in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty new to front end. i am exploring it and really loving it.

Here is some problem I encountered. It might be pretty simple.

I have 3 sections on right side of my web page. I want to add a feature to maximise, minimise and close to each of these sections. 
  I am successfull in implementing it using jquery SlideUp() and slideDown() methods.

I am having the buttons like this:

```
<h2 id = "Heading" style="background-color: grey ;">Movie Names      
<button  id = "minimise" > - </button>
<button id = "maximise" >  + </button>
<button id = "close" > x </button>
</h2>
```

In my webpage i see a gap between these buttons. I am not sure how to get rid of this space. I want to see something like how windows maximise, minimise and close buttons look.

One more question is how can I add space between Movie Names and these buttons because i want to adjust the positon of these buttons.

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible for us to help with visual problems that we cannot visualise. Can you link to a page showing the problem, or set up a JS Fiddle, perhaps?

Comment: You can get rid (or add) space between elements with CSS margin/padding, i.e. `.button { margin: 0; padding: 0; } //removes all `. And absolute positioning can be done with CSS `position: absolute`.  More info about CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 2):

It's likely due to the whitespace caused by line wrapping.  `button` elements are inline, and so whitespace appearing next to them will appear inline as well.

See if this makes a difference:

```
<h2 id="Heading" style="background-color:grey;">Movie Names
  <button  id="minimise">-</button
  ><button id="maximise">+</button
  ><button id="close">x</button
></h2>
```

**Edit:** Here you can see the difference in JSfiddle.  [Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/uJYxn/) vs. [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/uJYxn/1/).  In the second example, there is no whitespace between the button elements.  However, they may appear to have whitespace due to margins, outlines, etc., which you can control through CSS.

Comment: Hey I am trying to join those buttons. I dont want to see space between these buttons. Looks like your code is better than my code. but it didnt solve the issue

Comment: What do you mean by "join those buttons"?

Comment: You can see some grey area between the buttons right. I dont want to see them. Right most edge of - button and left most edge of + button must be same. Just like the minimize and maximise buttons in windows

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying when I wrote "they may appear to have whitespace due to margins, outlines, etc., which you can control through CSS."  Try setting the `border` property (specifically the `border-width` property) on your buttons, and ensure the `margin` is 0.